# Permission denied when installing ghc using stack setup

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm following http://seanhess.github.io/2015/08/04/practical-haskell-getting-started.html to get started with the stack tool.

```
$> stack --version
Version 0.1.3.1, Git revision 908b04205e6f436d4a5f420b1c6c646ed2b804d7
```

In the step "Installing GHC" I get `Permission denied`:

```
$> stack setup
Run from outside a project, using implicit global config
Using resolver: lts-3.2 from global config file: /Users/karl/.stack/global/stack.yaml
Preparing to download ghc-7.10.2 .../Users/karl/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-7.10.2.tar.bz2.tmp: 
openBinaryFile: permission denied (Permission denied)
```

Is this expected (a bug in the guide) or a bug in `stack`?

Running the same command with `sudo` seems to solve the problem. Is this the intended method?

```
$> sudo stack setup
Password:
Downloaded ghc-7.10.2.                                      
Installed GHC.     
stack will use a locally installed GHC
For more information on paths, see 'stack path' and 'stack exec env'
To use this GHC and packages outside of a project, consider using:
stack ghc, stack ghci, stack runghc, or stack exec
```

I'm running a fresh install of OS X 10.10.4 (Yosemite).

Comment: `sudo` seems appropriate... it does say it downloaded and installed the GHC complier...

Comment: I was maybe a little unclear ... yes `sudo stack setup` solved the problem. My questions was if using sudo is the expected way (that is, there is a bug in the guide I was following) or if there is some other preferred method.

Comment: This may be a string question, but do you have read / write permissions for your home directory? Who is the current owner of the `.stack` directory in your home?

Comment: @JustinWood I have read/write permission for my home directory. I'm the owner of  the `.stack` directory `drwxr-xr-x  10 karl  staff    340 Aug 26 00:54 .stack`.

Comment: Probably a directory under your `~/.stack` is owned by root. At the cost of recompiling modules doing a `/bin/rm -rf ~/.stack` is pretty safe. Then just do a `stack setup` again.

Comment: You shouldn't need `sudo` within your own home directory, for stack or anything else. I second user5402's suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion by @user5402 I found, that for some reason, `~/.stack/programs` was owned by root.

After removing the `.stack` directory `stack setup` worked as expected.